# Generic TypeScript interface with mixed member types

Tags: generics, typescript, interface, union, intersection

For several HTML forms, I want to configure inputs and deal with their values. My types have the following structure (you may copy it to TypeScript Playground http://www.typescriptlang.org/play to see it in action):

```
interface InputConfig {
    readonly inputType: "text" | "password" | "list"
    readonly attributes?: ReadonlyArray<string>
    readonly cssClasses?: ReadonlyArray<string>
}

interface Inputs<T extends InputConfig | string | string[]> {
    readonly username: (T & InputConfig) | (T & string)
    readonly password: (T & InputConfig) | (T & string)
    readonly passwordConfirmation: (T & InputConfig) | (T & string)
    readonly firstname: (T & InputConfig) | (T & string)
    readonly lastname: (T & InputConfig) | (T & string)
    readonly hobbies: (T & InputConfig) | (T & string[])
}

type InputConfigs = Inputs<InputConfig> // case 1 (see below)
type InputValues = Inputs<string | string[]> // case 2 (see below)

const configs: InputConfigs = {
    username: {
        inputType: "text"
    },
    password: {
        inputType: "password"
    },
    passwordConfirmation: {
        inputType: "password"
    },
    firstname: {
        inputType: "text"
    },
    lastname: {
        inputType: "text"
    },
    hobbies: {
        inputType: "list"
    }
}

const values: InputValues = {
    username: "testuser1",
    password: "test1",
    passwordConfirmation: "test1",
    firstname: "Tester",
    lastname: "1",
    hobbies: ["a", "b", "c"]
}

const username: string = values.username
```

The most important advantage of this generic approach is the single point of field naming in the `Inputs` interface: The names `username`, `password`, `passwordConfirmation`,... are used by **both** `InputConfigs` **and** `InputValues` which makes renaming as easy as possible.

**Unfortunately, it does not work as expected since the last assignment `const username: string = values.username` is not accepted by the compiler:**

```
Type 'string | (string & InputConfig) | (string[] & InputConfig) | (string[] & string)' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'string[] & InputConfig' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I expected it to work because my understanding was:

- case 1: `T` is `InputConfig` and thus `username` is of type `InputConfig` because:

  - `T & InputConfig` = `InputConfig & InputConfig` = `InputConfig`
  - `T & string` = `InputConfig & string` = nothing
- case 2: `T` is `string | string[]` and thus `username` is of type `string` because:

  - `T & InputConfig` = `(string | string[]) & InputConfig` = nothing
  - `T & string` = `(string | string[]) & string` = `string`

Comment: My solution for type safe form / field states : http://formstate.github.io/ Works everywhere mobx works (react / angular / inferno / vue).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will take a look at it. MobX is on my watch list because it is a good approach to state management. But for now, I prefer a TypeScript-only solution (which the question is about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let's explore the type error you're getting. If I ask TypeScript for the type of `values.username` (by hovering over it in an editor) I get

```
values.username : string
                | (string & InputConfig)
                | (string[] & InputConfig)
                | (string[] & string)
```

TypeScript has come up with this type by instantiating `Inputs`'s `T` parameter to `string | string[]` and putting `username`'s type into disjunctive normal form:

```
(T & InputConfig) | (T & string)
// set T ~ (string | string[])
((string | string[]) & InputConfig) | ((string | string[]) & string)
// distribute & over |
((string & InputConfig) | (string[] & InputConfig)) | ((string & string) | (string[] & string))
// reduce (string & string) ~ string, permute union operands
string | (string & InputConfig) | (string[] & InputConfig) | (string[] & string)
```

Is a value of this type assignable to `string`? No! `username` could be a `string[] & InputConfig`, so `const x : string = values.username` is ill typed.

Contrast this with your other type,

```
configs.username : InputConfig | (InputConfig & string)
```

This type is assignable to `InputConfig`.

This is a shortcoming of type systems in general: they have a tendency to reject programs which nonetheless would work at runtime. *You* may know that `values.username` will always be a `string`, but you haven't proved it to the satisfaction of the type system, which is just a dumb mechanical formal system. I'd generally argue that well typed programs tend to be easier to understand, and (crucially) easier to *keep working* as you change the code over time. Nonetheless, working within an advanced type system like TypeScript is an acquired skill, and it's easy to get trapped down a blind alley trying to make the type system do what you want.

---

How can we fix this? I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to achieve, but I'm interpreting your question as "how can I reuse the field names of a record with a variety of different types?" This seems like a job for [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#mapped-types).

Mapped types are an advanced feature of TypeScript's type system, but the idea is simple: you declare your field names up front as a union of literal types, and then describe a variety of types derived from those field names. Concretely:

```
type InputFields = "username"
                 | "password"
                 | "passwordConfirmation"
                 | "firstname"
                 | "lastname"
                 | "hobbies"
```

Now, `InputConfigs` is a record with all of those `InputFields`, each typed as a (`readonly`) `InputConfig`. The TypeScript library provides some [useful type combinators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick) for this:

```
type InputConfigs = Readonly<Record<InputFields, InputConfig>>
```

[`Readonly`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/bcf84f49589eb00decd0567efcd6d9eb789d5452/lib/lib.d.ts#L1368) and [`Record`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/bcf84f49589eb00decd0567efcd6d9eb789d5452/lib/lib.d.ts#L1382) are defined respectively as:

```
type Readonly<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
}
type Record<K extends string, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
}
```

When applied to the types in question we get:

```
type InputConfigs = Readonly<Record<InputFields, InputConfig>>
// expand definition of Record
type InputConfigs = Readonly<{ [P in InputFields]: InputConfig; }>
// expand definition of Readonly
type InputConfigs = {
    readonly [Q in keyof { [P in InputFields]: InputConfig }]: { [P in InputFields]: InputConfig }[Q];
}
// inline keyof and subscript operators
type InputConfigs = {
    readonly [Q in InputFields]: InputConfig;
}
// expand InputFields indexer
type InputConfigs = {
    readonly username: InputConfig;
    readonly password: InputConfig;
    readonly passwordConfirmation: InputConfig;
    readonly firstname: InputConfig;
    readonly lastname: InputConfig;
    readonly hobbies: InputConfig;
}
```

---

`InputValues` is a bit trickier, because it doesn't map those field names to types in a uniform manner. `hobbies` is a `string[]` whereas all the other fields are `string`s. I don't wanna use `Record<InputFields, string | string[]>` because that throws away your knowledge of which fields are `string`s and which are `string[]`s. (Then you'd be stuck with the same type error as you had in the question.) Instead, let's flip this around and treat `InputValues` as the source of truth about the field names, and derive `InputFields` from it using [the `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).

```
type InputValues = Readonly<{
    username: string
    password: string
    passwordConfirmation: string
    firstname: string
    lastname: string
    hobbies: string[]
}>
type InputFields = keyof InputValues
type InputConfigs = Readonly<Record<InputFields, InputConfig>>
```

Now your code type checks without modification.

```
const configs: InputConfigs = {
    username: {
        inputType: "text"
    },
    password: {
        inputType: "password"
    },
    passwordConfirmation: {
        inputType: "password"
    },
    firstname: {
        inputType: "text"
    },
    lastname: {
        inputType: "text"
    },
    hobbies: {
        inputType: "list"
    }
}

const values: InputValues = {
    username: "testuser1",
    password: "test1",
    passwordConfirmation: "test1",
    firstname: "Tester",
    lastname: "1",
    hobbies: ["a", "b", "c"]
}

let usernameConfig: InputConfig = configs.username  // good!
let usernameValue: string = values.username  // great!
let hobbiesValue: string[] = values.hobbies  // even better!
```

If you have a lot of these types and you want to map them all to config types, I'd even go so far as to define a generic type combinator for deriving types like `InputConfigs` from `InputValues`:

```
type Config<T> = Readonly<Record<keyof T, InputConfig>>

type InputConfigs = Config<InputValues>
```

Comment: Well I must say, I find that delightful. Really an elegant solution. Many thanks for your help and your excellent answer.

Comment: Even if I do not expect a better answer (as in this case), I usually wait until the bounty period ends.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a union `Foo | Bar` and you want to use it as `Foo` you have two options:

## Use a type guard

In your case you just want it to be a `string` change

```
const username: string = values.username // ERROR
```

to

```
const username: string = typeof values.username === 'string' ? values.username : ''; // OKAY
```

## Use a type assertion

```
const username: string = values.username as string;
```

Note a [type assertion is you telling the compiler "I know better"](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html).

Comment: The type `InputValues` itself should do this (without having to write the member names more than once).