# Describe deeply nested object function result in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that fulfills following conditions:

**1)** It consumes an object, that can have any levels of nesting, like a State for Redux. On the end of nesting it has some instance of class, let's call it `Leaf`. So, sample object type can look like following:

```
type Sample = {
  nested1: {
    nested2: Leaf,
  },
  nonesting: Leaf
}
```

Or, it may look like this:

```
type Sample2 = {
  nested1: {
    nested2: {
      nested3: {
        nested4: Leaf
      }
    },
    nested5: {
      nested6: {
        nested7: Leaf
      }
    }
  },
  nested8: {
    nested9: Leaf
  }
}
```

Like for the Redux's State it does not matter. It depends on library user.

**2)** It returns an object that has exaclty the same structure as an input object, but all `Leaf` in this object is replaced with `ProcessedLeaf`.

And I want to be able to get access to this object's `ProcessedLeaf` like following:

```
result.nested1.nested2
```

#### Current state

This is results of my exploring:

```
interface InputObject {
  [key: string]: InputObject | Leaf
}

interface OutputObject {
  [key: string]: OutputObject | ProcessedLeaf
}

function process(input: InputObject): OutputObject;
```

However, when I try to access object with dot-notation, I get an error:

```
TS2339:Property 'nested2' does not exist on type 'ProcessedLeaf | OutputObject'.
Property 'nested2' does not exist on type 'ProcessedLeaf'.
```

Another attempt:

```
interface InputObject {
  [key: string]: InputObject | Leaf
}

type OutputObject<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: OutputObject<T[key]> | ProcessedLeaf
}

function process<T extends InputObject>(input: T): OutputObject<T>;
```

However, error is similar:

```
TS2339:Property 'nested2' does not exist on type 'ProcessedLeaf | OutputObject<{ nested2: Leaf; }>'.
Property 'nested2' does not exist on type 'ProcessedLeaf'.
```

I know that there is a way to call elements in the following way:

```
result['nested1']['nested2']
```

But there is no profit in it. I can just return `any` from function, and it will be the same.

Is it possible to create this kind of typing with current typescript?

Comment: Probably you have to wait until [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12424) to be solved.

Comment: @kimamula, yes, it is exactly what I have been looking for. Can you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there seems to be no way to achieve what you are trying to do.
With [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12424) get solved, perhaps you should be able to write something like the following.

```
type Tree<T, Leaf> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Leaf ? Leaf : Tree<T[K], Leaf>;
};
type ProcessedTree<T, Leaf, ProcessedLeaf> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Leaf ? ProcessedLeaf : ProcessedTree<T[K], Leaf, ProcessedLeaf>;
};

function process<T>(input: Tree<T, Leaf>): ProcessedTree<T, Leaf, ProcessedLeaf>;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create this kind of typing with current typescript?

No. Since you explicitly want to allow any point e.g. `a.b.c` to be either `Nested` or `Leaf` any truthful type definition would have this union. More docs on how to overcome the additional error you are getting : [Generic TypeScript interface with mixed member types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168636/generic-typescript-interface-with-mixed-member-types/44191545#44191545).

## Solution

I would reconsider *what is nested and what isn't* e.g. look at `$nest` in TypeStyle : http://typestyle.io/#/core/concept-interpolation